# PL/SQL oracle procedure dose not returen any value

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i Have this oracle procedure reading paramater with varchar value,and when i use this parameter value inside the procedure dose not work. Everything will be explained below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure test_pro(read_batch in varchar2 )

as
v_read_batches varchar2(500);
begin

v_read_batches := '''' || replace(read_batch, ',', ''',''') || '''';

--v_read_batches VALUE IS '100','1000','11','9200'

SELECT CODE,BANK_NAME_ARABIC,BANK_CODE,to_number(BATCH_ID)BATCH_ID FROM (select 1 CODE,PB.BANK_NAME_ARABIC ,to_char(PB.BANK_CODE)BANK_CODE,
CASE PB.BANK_CODE
    WHEN 1000
    THEN 1000 
    WHEN 100
    THEN 100  
    ELSE 9200 
  END batch_id
from BANKS PB 
WHERE PB.BANK_CODE IN (1000,100,11200)

union
SELECT 2 CODE,'Other Banks' other_banks,listagg(PB.BANK_CODE , ', ')
within group(order by  PB.BANK_CODE ) as BANK_CODE, 11 batch_id
 FROM BANKS  PB 
WHERE PB.BANK_CODE NOT IN (1000,100,9200))

WHERE to_char(BATCH_ID) IN (v_read_batches)                                                                            
   
end test_pro;
```

**Problem is when i put v_read_batches inside the sql condition it did not returen any value, when i execute
the below sql alone with same value in v_read_batches variable it works and reture the values !!**

> SELECT CODE,BANK_NAME_ARABIC,BANK_CODE,to_number(BATCH_ID)BATCH_ID
> FROM (select 1 CODE,PB.BANK_NAME_ARABIC
> ,to_char(PB.BANK_CODE)BANK_CODE, CASE PB.BANK_CODE
> WHEN 1000
> THEN 1000
> WHEN 100
> THEN 100
> ELSE 9200    END batch_id from BANKS PB  WHERE PB.BANK_CODE IN (1000,100,11200)
>
> union SELECT 2 CODE,'Other Banks' other_banks,listagg(PB.BANK_CODE ,
> ', ') within group(order by  PB.BANK_CODE ) as BANK_CODE, 11 batch_id
> FROM BANKS  PB  WHERE PB.BANK_CODE NOT IN (1000,100,9200))
>
> WHERE to_char(BATCH_ID) IN ('100','1000','11','9200')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot build a string like this and hope to use it iin an IN statement.  The elements in an IN clause are static, ie, if you code

```
col in ('123,456')
```

then we are looking for COL to match the string '123,456' not the elements 123 and 456.

You can convert your input string to rows via some SQL, eg

```
create table t as select '123,456,789' acct from dual

select distinct (instr(acct||',',',',1,level)) loc
from t
connect by level <= length(acct)- length(replace(acct,','))+1
```

Having done this, you could alter your procedure so that your

```
WHERE batch_id in (read_batch)
```

becomes

```
WHERE batch_id in (select distinct (instr(:batch||',',',',1,level)) loc
    from t
    connect by level <= length(:batch)- length(replace(:batch,','))+1
)
```

In the general sense, never let an input coming from the outside world be folded directly into a SQL statement. You create the risk of "SQL Injection" which is the most common way people get hacked.

Full video demo on the string-to-rows technique here:

https://youtu.be/cjvpXL3H64c?list=PLJMaoEWvHwFIUwMrF4HLnRksF0H8DHGtt